# NASM assembly reading file provided via command line arg

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have this code written in NASM assembly. I want to open a file that is provided via command line argument. Then I want to read the content. Unfortunately sys_open fails (the file_descriptor in rax register is wired 0xffffffffffffffffe). When I hardcode filename in section .data - program runs fine. It fails when I read filename via command line argument. Thanks for tips

code:

```
SYS_READ    equ 0
SYS_OPEN    equ 2
SYS_CLOSE   equ 3
SYS_EXIT    equ 60
O_RDONLY    equ 0

section .bss
    argc resb 1
    filename resb 10
    array resb  256
    number resb 1
    fd resb 8 

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    pop rax              ; pop argc value - should be 2
    cmp rax, 0x2    
    jne _sys_exit_1
    pop rax              ; pop addres pointing to "./prog"
    pop rax              ; pop addres pointing to filename
    mov [filename], rax
    call _sys_open
    mov [fd], rax        ; store file descriptor

_read_seq_loop: 
    call _sys_read

    xor rbx, rbx
    mov bl, byte [number] ; store read number in bl register
    cmp bl, 0
    mov byte [array + rbx], 1 ;save it to array 
    jne _read_seq_loop

    jmp _sys_exit_0


_sys_open:
    mov rax, SYS_OPEN
    mov rdi, filename
    mov rsi, O_RDONLY
    mov rdx, 0
    syscall
    ret

_sys_read:
    mov rax, SYS_READ
    mov rdi, [fd]
    mov rsi, number
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
    ret

_sys_exit_1:
    mov rax, SYS_EXIT
    mov rdi, 1
    syscall

_sys_exit_0:
    mov rax, SYS_EXIT
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these two changes and I think you'll see right away, that instead of passing a pointer to a string, your passing a pointer to a pointer that points to a string.

```
        pop     rax              ; pop argc value - should be 2
        cmp     rax, 0x2    
        jne     _sys_exit_1
        pop    rax              ; pop addres pointing to "./prog"
        pop    rdi              ; pop address of ARG0
       call    _sys_open
        mov   [fd], rax        ; store file descriptor
```

As RDI is already set, it can be taken out of routine

```
_sys_open:
        mov    rax, SYS_OPEN
        mov    rsi, O_RDONLY
        mov    rdx, 0
        syscall
        ret
```

Comment: That's not ARG0, it's `argv[1]`.

Comment: @PeterCordes. `argv[1]` is an HLL construct, irrelevant to this method of gleaning pointers for arguments passed by user.

Comment: It's only by convention that the program name is passed as the first argument.  A caller could put anything they want in the first element of the array they pass to [`execve(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).  re: terminology: the x86-64 System V ABI (Figure 3.9: Initial Process Stack) calls it the "Argument pointers", and doesn't say anything about the first one being special.  But it does use the term `argc`. Anyway, if anyone's making up high-level terminology, it's you with ARG0. Calling it `argv[1]` is well-understood, and the ABI doc does mention the C `argv` name.